# Powershell check log file and restart service if error code found

Tags: powershell, loops, logging

I'm pretty new to PowerShell and I'm trying to get a script running which checks for an error code in the last 5 lines of a log file. If the script finds an error, it should restart a service otherwise it should loop back to the top and do it again.

```
if(Get-Content C:\x\x\x\Log.log -last 5  | Select-String -pattern "Error" -Quiet){
  Restart-Service -Name xxx -Force
}
else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to include your code inside an endless loop (wouldn't recommend it):

```
while($true)
{
   if(Get-Content C:\a\b\c\log.log -Tail 5 | Select-String -Pattern "Error")
   {
      Write-Host "Error found - restarting service..."
      Restart-Service -Name myService -Force
   }
   Start-Sleep 5
}
```

This will read the last 5 lines of the log, if any of those lines match the provided pattern it will write out that it is restarting the service then force a restart of the service, wait 5 seconds and go back to the start and check again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct so far. However, the `-last` parameter does not exist in `Get-Content`. Try it with `-Tail`.

More infos: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1